# Retrieving XML type records from Oracle Database in QTP

Tags: xml, database, testing, qtp

I want to fetch records from an Oracle database that contain XML files in them. When I try to fetch other columns from the same table, it successfully returns, like a number or a text, but the column with XML type records gives an unspecific error while executing the query.

code:

```
Dim strConn
strConn = //conn string 

Dim obConnect
Dim obRecset 


Set obConnect =CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set obRecset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

obConnect.Open strConn

Dim queryStr

Dim i,j
For j=1 to 10 

  datatable.SetCurrentRow(j)

  i= datatable.Value("A","Global") ------------->>>>>> taking value from datatable

  queryStr = "select  tran_doc_xml from transaction where tran_doc_xml like 

  '%Metadata%' and uniq_descr_value_desc = '"&i&"'" ----------->>>>> fetching XML type record

  Set obRecset = obConnect.Execute(queryStr) ----->>>>>>> Error in this line

  msgbox obRecset.Fields.Item(0)

Next
```

Are there any suggestions on how to retrieve XML records from the DB?

Answer (score 1):

How about using a query like

```
SELECT t.tran_doc_xml
FROM transaction t
WHERE t.tran_doc_xml.extract('/NodeLevel1/NodeLevel2/text()').getStringVal()
    like '%Metadata%';
```